# Ubuntu bind9 public host name

Tags: ubuntu

I have created a DNS Server using bind9 and it works on my home network. I am able to ping my other machines on the network.

Now, I want to publish this host name to the actual machine. I know the host name can be set throught /etc/hosts. Is there any way to publish the hostname to the actual machine without changing the hosts file? So that when I type hostname it displays the DNS name that is set.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You can run a private dns server with forwarding.

Comment: Ok. Does bind9 provide forwarding?

Comment: It can be [so configured](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).